# Blazor Server hreflang canonical link problem | PageSpeed Insights

Tags: seo, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I am encountering a peculiar issue while using the Google Website Test for my multilingual Blazor Server App developed with .NET 7. When I conduct the test using the URL https://ghostlyinc.com/de-DE, I receive an error message indicating an invalid canonical link. Interestingly, this error doesn't occur when I use https://ghostlyinc.com/de-DE/ (with a trailing slash) instead.

Upon inspecting the source code of my page in the browser, I noticed that the canonical link in the header is set to https://ghostlyinc.com/de-DE (without the trailing slash), leading me to believe that the version without the slash should be the correct one. I also tried setting the link in the header with a trailing slash, but then only the version without the slash is valid in the Google Website Test.

Moreover, the URL https://ghostlyinc.com/en-US/ works seamlessly in both variants (with and without the slash), which is my default language setting. Could this be a bug on Google's part, or is there another possible reason for this issue? You can verify this by testing my website yourself. I look forward to your suggestions for troubleshooting.

So far, I have tried different approaches to remedy the problem. I have set the canonical link in my header both with and without a trailing slash to see how this affects the results in the Google Website Test. Oddly, the validity of the link in the test seems to be exactly the opposite: if the canonical link has a trailing slash, the version without the slash is valid in the test, and vice versa. Despite these attempts, I have not yet been able to find a solution that provides consistent results

Comment: You are aware that the URI with the slash is not the same resource as the one without?

Comment: I am aware that the URI with a slash is not the same resource as the one without, which is why it seems very strange that in the Google test it only works when the resources are different. That is, if the link in the header does not have a slash and I test the URI with a slash.